# App Crashes while getting all the Frames from a video using AVAssetImageGenerator for long videos

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have successfully extracted all the frames from a video and it is working fine for smaller videos but when I try to extract frames from a video more than 60 secs the app crashes on device.

I am extracting 30 frames per second from the video.

**Following is the code I have written :-**

```
var  videoSec = Float64(0)

 func startImageConversion(){
        let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(self.savedVideoURL)
        videoSec = self.getVideoTime(filePath)
        videoImagesArray =  self.getImagesArrayFromVideo(filePath)
        print("Images Count \(videoImagesArray.count)")
    }
```

// MARK: - Video Editor Functions

```
    func getImagesArrayFromVideo(filePath:NSURL) -> NSMutableArray
    {
        let imageArray = NSMutableArray()
        print("Video Sec is ",videoSec)
        let vidSec = Float64(videoSec)

        let theOpts = [
            AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : true,
            AVURLAssetReferenceRestrictionsKey : 0 // AVAssetReferenceRestrictions.RestrictionForbidNone
        ]
        let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: filePath, options: theOpts)
        let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        generator.maximumSize = CGSize(width: Double(self.view.frame.size.width),
                                       height: Double(self.view.frame.size.height))

        generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = false
        generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero
        generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero
        let vid_length:CMTime = asset.duration
        let fps = vid_length.timescale
        print("Video Lenght :- \(vid_length) FPS is :- \(fps)")


        let mainValue = Float64(vid_length.value)

        let divide = vidSec*30
        let byVal = mainValue/divide


        for i in 0.stride(through: Float64(vid_length.value), by: byVal)
        {

            var image:CGImage!//UIImage()
            let divident = Float64(i)
//            let mileSec = Float64(divident / 1000)
//            print(Sec)
            image  = self.generateVideoThumbs(filePath, second: divident,
                                              thumbWidth: Double(self.view.frame.size.width),
                                              generator : generator,
                                              fps : fps
            )

            if image != nil {

                imageArray.addObject(image)

            }
        }

        print("value of Array is ",imageArray.count)

        return imageArray

    }



 private func getVideoTime(url: NSURL) -> Float64
    {
        let videoTime = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)
        print("videoTime.preferredRate = \(videoTime.preferredRate)")
        return CMTimeGetSeconds(videoTime.duration)
    }



 private func generateVideoThumbs(url: NSURL, second: Float64, thumbWidth: Double, generator:AVAssetImageGenerator, fps: CMTimeScale) -> CGImage! {
        let thumbTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(second), fps)
        var actualTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
        print("thumbTime - \(thumbTime)")
        do {
            let ref = try generator.copyCGImageAtTime(thumbTime, actualTime: &actualTime)
            print("actualTime - \(actualTime)")
            return ref//UIImage(CGImage: ref)
        }catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
     }
```

**Everything works fine if the video is less than 60 secs or so.
Also it works fine on simulator but disconnects the device without any warning or error.**
[image]
Any Help will appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Don't you have a memory warning in console? That could be the whole issue since it seems to be working for video consuming less memory. If YES, try to use Instruments Memory Leaks, Profiling, Allocations, etc, to try to find which part may the guilty and try to find a solution for it.

Comment: @Larme No warning in the console, It just disconnects the device.I tried instruments as well for the memory leak but No luck.

Comment: this might be memory issues please have look the memory meter in Xcode while debugging your code  if your app consume memory more than 450 mb then this memory issue.

Comment: @MDavid It is using excessive memory but what will be the solution of it.
How can I ensure it doesn't go above 450mb but still works.

Comment: image  = self.generateVideoThumbs(filePath, second: divident,
                                              thumbWidth: Double(self.view.frame.size.width),
                                              generator : generator,
                                              fps : fps cache is hold by  UIImage can change  it to UIImage method imagewithcontentsoffile i think try this once

Comment: @dragoneye can you please elaborate your comment.

Comment: @DeepakSharma main issue is your array, don't store your images in array i-e as files or in core data for temporary amount of time I hope this will help you.

Comment: you are extracted images and saving using CGimage or UIimages inside a array now these images holding memory cache and never releasing it . so fetch image from video and save loop images using UIImage  contentsOfFile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
autoreleasepool{
if image != nil {
var newImage:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
                imageArray.addObject(image)
            }
}
```

As in the above answer dive mentioned its the problem with memory.
Just use this code. I have tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: This solves the problem of allocating images inside a loop, and even if setting something like image: UIImage? = ....   and later, image=nil, the memory is not release while inside a loop, but the autoreleasepool solves this.

Answer (score 1):

Core Graphics doesn't support autorelease pool in Objective C, but Swift ARC can handle CF types, anyway you can still have issues with `CGImage` releasing in some cases, maybe it's the case and you obviously have an issue with the size of your `imageArray` and I'm sure that your device is disconnected because of `out of memory` SIGTERM. iOS Simulator use shared memory on your modern 15" develop MacBook, so, everything will work there.

I suggest you to rewrite your `generateVideoThumbs(...)` function and use `UIImage` as return value (you've tried it already as I can see, just return your solution with `UIImage`):

```
private func generateVideoThumbs(url: NSURL, second: Float64, thumbWidth: Double, generator:AVAssetImageGenerator, fps: CMTimeScale) -> UIImage! {
        let thumbTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(second), fps)
        var actualTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
        print("thumbTime - \(thumbTime)")
        do {
            let ref = try generator.copyCGImageAtTime(thumbTime, actualTime: &actualTime)
            let resultImage = UIImage.init(ref)
            print("actualTime - \(actualTime)")
            return resultImage
        }catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
     }
```

And second, I suggest you to save your images to disk and store only links in your `imageArray`. Something like this:

```
if image != nil {
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let filename = NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(i).png")
    try? data.write(to: filename)
    imageArray.addObject(filename)
}
```

Then you can extract your images from URLs and do whatever you plan to do with them. It allows you to avoid memory pressure and use your array in any way you want (copy, forward to another class, etc).

> P.S. I wrote the code without compilation, but I think that idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is a memory issue. `copeCGImageAtTime` is synchronous in main thread and there is a problem if you put it into a for loop.

Use `- (void)generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)requestedTimes completionHandler:(AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler)handler;`

rather than `- (nullable CGImageRef)copyCGImageAtTime:(CMTime)requestedTime actualTime:(nullable CMTime *)actualTime error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)outError CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;`.

Have another try.

Have a nice day.